# Gitlab: "/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a fresh install of gitlab-ee on a EC2 instance. Followed [the instructions](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu) to the letter.

The external url is http://`<IP_ADDR>`/gitlab (since I don't have a domain I can use)

My problem is that while gitlab successfully installs, when I try to access it, it gives me a 502 error. `cat /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log` shows me the error in the title.

I tried to install it on my local machine and the same problem occurs. I should mention I did have apache installed on both machines prior to installing gitlab.

Steps I've tried:

- Uncomment `nginx['enable'] = True` in `gitlab.rb`
- Uninstall and reinstall `gitlab-ee`
- Run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` several times.

Comment: Which instructions did you follow? Do you have a `nginx` configuration snippet you can share?

Comment: Gitlab installation instructions as shown [here](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu). As far as nginx configuration goes, all I've done is uncomment nginx['enable']. Also, it works on my local machine after rebooting it but not on the instance.

Comment: Have you allowed HTTP through the instance's firewall?

Comment: They have separate instructions for AWS; is there a reason you're not following those?

Comment: Why do you have both Apache and Nginx, and which one is actually handling incoming HTTP connections?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was that the instance I was running on had too little memory. This was proven after using a separate nginx server, which showed some "out of memory" errors in `runsvdir` or whichever that service.

It was solved by using a DigitalOcean droplet with One-click install.

To run gitlab you need at least **4 GB** RAM, at least for version 11+.

Thanks for everyone for the help and I hope this question helps someone.